# C# SQL query run time error using Nuget System.Data.SqlClient?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This is my code:

```
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(findIt)))
{
    string query = @"select top (@Num) * from dbo.main where (Data = @FindIt) ";         

    // Data-> ntext
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        myCon.Open();

        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num",limit);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FindIt", SqlDbType.NText)).Value = findIt;

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); // Run time error

            myReader.Close();
            myCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types ntext and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I don't know what it means and how to fix it

Comment: did you try nvarchar as datatype in your parameter?

Comment: Maybe you can try ```Like``` instead of ```=```?

Comment: no need for mycon.close() either since you are in using

Comment: Why are you using `ntext` in the first place? That was deprecated loooooooong ago. Unless this is an ancient database, there's really no excuse for not using `nvarchar`. If it's your database, you should change it.

Comment: Sidenote, I don't see any use for the DataTable you have created, if you don't need it outside this scope then I would also put that creation in a `using`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ntext` data type does not support equality comparisons. That data type has been deprecated for a long time and should not be used in a new database and should be changed in an existing database. Use `nvarchar` instead if you possibly can. If you really must use `ntext` in the database, you have three options in your query:

- Convert the database value to `nvarchar` and use `nvarchar` for your parameter, then perform an equality comparison.
- Perform a `LIKE` comparison.
- Use the `PATINDEX` function to effectively do a `LIKE` comparison and get the index of the match, which should be 1 for equality.

Note that a `LIKE` comparison with no wildcards is effectively an equality comparison.